# SQLite3 database not showing entries on console via NSLog (Saving data to the DB works)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite, console

Working on a simple TimeTracker App. You start a timer, wait a certain time, stop the clock and save spent minutes to a SQLite3 database. All is working as expected, when I tap on save I get a confirmation that record was saved but I can't get the saved entries shown on the console. As seen in the screenshot below I have a `show button` which should show me all my saved entries in the console including timestamp but nothing happens when I tap the button.

I think the problem is related to the search query but I can't figure our whats wrong.

From my understanding the query is looking for the timestamp (column 0) and the spent minutes (column 1) but it doesn't work, please help.

```
   NSLog(@"Timestamp: %s - Timing: %s", sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0), sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1));
```

SQLite database is really simple, I only want to save one value > spent minutes.
Maybe the database is not created correctly??

Database Creation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    databasePath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"timings.db"]];

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath] == NO) 
    {
        const char *dbPath = [databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &timings) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            char *errormsg;
            const char *sql_stmt =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TIMINGS(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TIME INTEGER)";

            if (sqlite3_exec(timings, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errormsg) != SQLITE_OK) 
            {
                self.statusLabel.text = @"Failed to create database";
            }
            sqlite3_close(timings);
        } 
        else 
        {
            self.statusLabel.text = @"Failed to open/create database.";
        }

    }
}
```

Show saved entries on console:

```
-(IBAction)showButton:(id)sender
{
    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &timings) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *queryStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT TIMESTAMP, TIME FROM TIMINGS"];

        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(timings, [queryStatement UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSLog(@"Timestamp: %s - Timing: %s", sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0), sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1));
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(timings);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screernshot]

Comment: Are you sure showButton is getting called? Put an NSLog(@"in showButton") at the beginning of it to make sure.

Comment: Yes, showButton will be called. Put an NSLog at the beginning. Console Output: 2012-04-01 09:54:19.982 RangeManager[49985:f803] Show Button tapped

Comment: Try this [Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887785/sqlite-database-load-fails-issue-with-sqlite-prepare-statement-iphone-xcod/9888240#9888240

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a friend of mine just realized that I made a big mistake, I totally forgot to CREATE the column 'TIMESTAMP' I'm trying to read out here. If you look at this line:  `"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TIMINGS(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TIME INTEGER)";` You see that I have not created the timestamp column. Last but not least is TIMESTAMP a protected keyword in SQL you are not allowed to use. To save a timestamp I just created and renamed the column and now it's working. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Put `NSLog(@"Error. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));` after each database operation completed. (ie; after, sqlite3_step, sqlite3_prepare etc). When you get data base, which was created by simulator, from Library/ApplicationSupport ....., you can open that using terminal and see the contents. Or using SQLite Manager plug in of mozilla you can open database and see contents graphically.

Comment: NSLog(@"Error. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database)); is very useful. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do any rows get returned from your query? Open your sqlite database using a browser (http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) and check the data is actually being saved.

Then rerun your sql in the browser to test the query, and finally put a breakpoint on 
`-(IBAction)showButton:(id)sender` and step thru

Comment: Where is my SQLite3 database from iPhone Simulator stored? Can't find following folder: /User/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/GUID/Documents > What I have is: /User/Library/Application Support but no subfolder called iPhone Simulator.

Comment: Finally found the folder. Had to remove hidden flag first via Terminal: chflags nohidden /users/[username]/library

Comment: Was able to verify with SQL browser that app does save data successfully. When I set a breakpoint on the IBAction showButton I see no strange behavior but I still get no rows listed at all with my query. Even an additional NSLog within the while is not shown on the console. When I put an NSLog BEFORE the while function I see an output.

Comment: Run your query "SELECT TIMESTAMP, TIME FROM TIMINGS" on your database using sqlite browser, does it return results?

Comment: Strange, when I run: SELECT TIMESTAMP, TIME FROM TIMINGS > I get: no such column: TIMESTAMP ... When I run: SELECT TIME FROM TIMINGS > I get my saved records listed (without the timestamp)