# Cannot select from sqlite3 database

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

I have some problem with reading from sqlite3 database.

```
-(void) readMessengesFromDatabase {
    sqlite3 *database;

    messenges = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Connection OK");
        const char *sqlStatement = "select * from MessagesData";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) NSLog(@"connect to table OK");    else NSLog(@"connect to table FALSE");
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) { //не проходит условие
            NSLog(@"Connection to table OK");
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSLog(@"Read rows OK");
                NSString *dbMessageID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
                NSString *dbMessageText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                NSString *dbMessageDate = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                NSString *dbMediaOrNot = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];

                Message *messege = [[Message alloc] initWithName:dbMessageText messageID:dbMessageID messageDate:dbMessageDate mediaOrNot:dbMediaOrNot];

                [messenges addObject:messege];

                [messege release];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);    
}
```

My first NSLog shows me what connection to database is ok. But next step "select * from MessagesData" and `if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) NSLog(@"connect to table OK");    else NSLog(@"connect to table FALSE");` shows me "connect to table FALSE". Tried select from my database's table whith Terminal and got error **"unable to open database file"** . Where is my mistake? I don't see any problems in my code...

Comment: Any reason you've chosen not to use Core Data?

Comment: I would be happy to use Core Data, but my programming level is to low yet to use it :)

Comment: @Eugene I heard about FMDB too late. my project is almost ready and  would not want to edit it at this stage...

Comment: are you calling this function from thread ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print the error code returned by `sqlite3_prepare_v2` it will be a lot easier to diagnose the problem. The numeric values can be found on [this page](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html).

```
int errorCode = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);
if(errorCode != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Connect to table failed: %d", errorCode); 
}
```

However, if you cannot even select from the database in the `sqlite3` command line tool, I suggest you check that the file exists, is readable and in the correct format.

Try to reproduce the error in your simulator (failing that, copy the database file to your computer e.g. using Organizer). Try to run the query using `sqlite3` (I know you did try that, but make sure you are checking the following).

If you are getting the message `Error: file is encrypted or is not a database`, it means that the database file is corrupt. If you get `Error: no such table:`, it means your database does not exist, **is empty**, or simply hasn't got the table. If you get (as in your question): `Error: unable to open database` (you get this during the opening of sqlite, not when performing the query), it means that sqlite cannot read the file (for example permissions).

Comment: My error code is "1". What can it be? Missing database? Tried to run my older project versions, they have same error (but it worked before!).

Comment: Are you sure the file exists at this path? `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: databasePath]` will tell you

Comment: Very strange. Just opened database from Simulator folder, in fact database file is exist but it isn't content any tables. But my database from project has 2 tables.

Comment: I repeated my query and get the same error as the in my previous post. What is more, when I deleted database from simulator and copied it from PC manually my project stared to work exactly the way I want to. So I assume that the problem is contained in coping process.

Answer (score 1):

well i m guessing ur Database is not being able to connect. 
Try My Answer From [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887785/sqlite-database-load-fails-issue-with-sqlite-prepare-statement-iphone-xcod/9888240#9888240)...

I mentioned few things here and i believe u ll be just Fine

Let me know it worked

Comment: Also I tried to run my older project versions, they have same error but they worked before. Maybe can it be xCode or Simulator bug?

Answer (score 0):

write a code for check that table exist or not. and before u execute the query select u should check that create table if not exists ....

NSLog(@"Connection OK");

```
 sqlite3_exec(database,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MessagesData (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
                             "FirstName TEXT,LastName TEXT"));

   const char *sqlStatement = "select * from MessagesData";
```

If it work please like it